# Updating Composable View child when Data Changes in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Compose view hierarchy where I'm using a child Composable, EventView, within a parent Composable, MainEventView. The data for the child Composable is obtained from a ViewModel which contains a list of Event objects. However, when I update the list of events in the ViewModel, the EventView Composable does not update to reflect the changes. The Event class is a Java class extending RealmObject if thats relevant.

Here is the code:

```
public class Event extends RealmObject {

    private String name;

    public String realmGet$name() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

This my compose view that is used as a child view in another compose view

```
@Composable
fun EventView(
    event: Event?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Text(text= event.name)
}
```

The compose view using this as a child view is shown below

```
@Composable
fun MainEventView(
    event: Event?,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    EventView(event= event)
}
```

This is shown on my screen using a viemodel that contains a list of the Events

```
@Composable
fun MainEventsScreen(
    model: EventsBuilderViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val events by model.events.collectAsState()

    MainEventView(event= events[0])
}
```

The viewmodel itself

```
class EventsBuilderViewModel: ViewModel() {
    private var _events = MutableStateFlow(ArrayList<Event?>().apply {
        repeat(11) {
            add(null)
        }
    })
    val events: StateFlow<ArrayList<Event?>> = _events
}
```

When I update the list, EventView composable does not update. How can I achieve this?

Comment: In sample code you are showing single event[0], which is null at first. Then you sure you update 0th index event from viewmodel?

Comment: Yes, its null then updates. The thing is it doesn’t refresh. When I leave the Screen and get back it reflects the new value

Comment: I used exact same code above with one exception: instead of `Event` class i used `String`. Then updated _events with `_events.value = arrayListOf("New Text", "New Text 2")` with 2 seconds delay, UI is updated. `StateFlow` has `distinctUntilChanged` built-in, maybe it has sth to do with `RealmObject`?

Comment: That is why I mentioned that its a Java Class extending RealmObject. I’ll try run exact code without that and see too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a mutableStateListOf would be a better approach in your use case.

```
class EventsBuilderViewModel: ViewModel() {
   
   
    val events = mutableStateListOf<Event?>()
        .apply {
            repeat(15) {
                add(null)
            }
        }
    
    fun update(index){
        events[index] = events[index].copy(name = "")
    }

}
```

```
@Composable
fun MainEventsScreen(
    model: EventsBuilderViewModel = viewModel()
) {
    val events by remember{viewModel.events}

    MainEventView(events)
}
```

Comment: I get the error "Type 'TypeVariable(T)' has no method 'getValue(Nothing?, KProperty<*>)' and thus it cannot serve as a delegate" so I just accessed model.events directly and it worked.